# Under what conditions my code would run into error/failure?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Please refer below code -

```
exports.ticketList = function(req, res, next) {
    Ticket.find(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            //---- Error Handler ----
            return next(err);
        }
        res.render('ticketListView', { ticketList: data });
    });
}
```

Here I am trying to fetch data from mongoDB. And I can successfully get the data.

**But I just wanted to know under what conditions my code would run into error / failure.**

Answer (score 0):

**The empty list case:** If you don't handle empty lists in TicketListView, then you need to check that data.length > 0 before rendering ticketListView.

Answer (score 0):

One possible condition: if the app cannot connect to mongodb